# Proving log properties

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How would I go about proving that **log<sub>a</sub>(x) = c * log<sub>b</sub>(x)** for some constant **c**

Would **c** just be **$\frac{b}{a}$** for all instances?

Comment: what's your math background and what have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just notice that:

$$\log_a(x)=\frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}$$

So the constant you are searching for is:

$$\frac{1}{\log_b(a)}$$